# How to get the current language in Django?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, django-i18n

How can I get the current language in Django?

Comment: Please be specific. 'The language of my web' - do you mean the web request, the web server, or what?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Functions of particular interest are `django.utils.translation.get_language()` which returns the language used in the current thread. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language).

Comment: Caveat: *Returns None if translations are temporarily deactivated (by deactivate_all() or when None is passed to override()). Before Django 1.8, get_language() always returned LANGUAGE_CODE when translations were deactivated.*

Answer (score 112):

Or you can also get this in your views

```
request.LANGUAGE_CODE
```

Comment: I voted this up (from -1 for some reason). Note the following (from http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference "with static (middleware-less) translation, the language is in settings.LANGUAGE_CODE, while with dynamic (middleware) translation, it's in request.LANGUAGE_CODE."

Comment: That link is dead, and I see no reason for not using the documented accepted solution above: `django.utils.translation.get_language()`

Comment: trying to get the language in e.g. models would not be possible if there is no request yet. I think the ```django.utils.translation.get_language()``` is always a better solution.

Comment: What about to get the current language in a template?

Comment: @azmeuk this might be useful for you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates

Comment: Thanks been googlin this for 20 minutes. For template use {{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}

Answer (score 48):

**Be careful of the method you use to get the language**. Depending on which method, Django will use different ways and informations to *determine* the right language to use.

When using the `django.utils.translation.get_language()` function, it's linked to the **thread** language. Before Django 1.8, it always returned  `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` when translations were disabled. If you want to manually override the thread language, you can use the `override()` or `activate()` functions, which is not very explicitly named, but well, still useful:

```python
from django.utils import translation

with translation.override('fr'):
    print(_("Hello")) # <= will be translated inside the with block

translation.activate('fr') # <= will change the language for the whole thread.
# You then have to manually "restore" the language with another activate()
translation.activate('en') # <= change languages manually
```

If you want django to check the **path and/or request (language cookie, ...)**, which is a lot more common e.g. `www.example.com/en/<somepath>` vs `www.example.com/fr/<somepath>`, use [`django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request(request, check_path=False)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request). Also, it will always return a valid language set in `settings.LANGUAGES`

I found it not very easy to find these differences through Google about this subject so here it is for further reference.

Comment: Note that it is `django.utils.translation`, not translations. There is a misspelling in the link provided. In the snippet it is correct.

Comment: +1 for the difference between `django.utils.translation.get_language()` and `django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request(request, check_path)`. If in view, you should use the latter with `check_path = True` to get the language your template will get rendered in.

Answer (score 11):

Just to add that if you do use `django.utils.translation.get_language()` then you should bear in mind that if that section of code will be called asynchronously (e.g. as a celery task) then this approach won't work due to it running in a different thread.

Comment: The obvious approach here would be to pass language as task parameter, and then set language with translation.activate(language)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [these template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#other-tags) in Django's templating language:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

Current language code: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}<br>

{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}

{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}RTL <br>{% endif %}

{% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as lang %}

Language code: {{ lang.code }}<br>
Name of language: {{ lang.name_local }}<br>
Name in English: {{ lang.name }}<br>
Bi-directional: {{ lang.bidi }}
Name in the active language: {{ lang.name_translated }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current language with [LANGUAGE_CODE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#language-code) and [get_language()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language) in Django Views as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import get_language

def test(request):
    print(request.LANGUAGE_CODE) # en
    print(get_language()) # en
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And, you can get the current language with `LANGUAGE_CODE` and [get_current_language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language) in Django Templates as shown below. *`get_current_language` needs to load [i18n](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#i18n):

```
{% "index.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }} {% "en" %}

{% get_current_language as current_language %}
{{ current_language }} {% "en" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the system's [`locale`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) for language information.

Comment: You're moderated to -3, but I think the question is vague - "the current language of my web". Not your fault for guessing this means OS.