# Django - Store the language of user in database

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I am able to change the language of the user with built-in function of django

```
path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

In order to send email to user translated in his language, I want to know the activated language of the user.

How can I save the language of the in db?

Is there another way to know the language?

This is the session:

```
from django.utils import translation
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `User` model, you need to add a new field:

```
    interface_language = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

Then you need to create middleware like this:

```
from django.utils import translation

def language_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
        if user is not None and user.is_authenticated:
            translation.activate(user.interface_language)
        response = get_response(request)
        translation.deactivate()
        return response
    return middleware
```

The middleware needs to be added to your settings after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticaitonMiddleware',
    'language_middleware',
    # ...
]
```

Alternatively, you can also use a Pypi package like [`django-user-language-middleware`](https://pypi.org/project/django-user-language-middleware/).

Comment: Inevitably, If `user is None or not user.is_authenticated`, you will use `get_language()`, [no](https://github.com/laura-barluzzi/django-user-language-middleware/blob/c1498fe74bef89d4e998b4a725f727b71c748e21/user_language_middleware/middleware.py#L37)?

Comment: I want to save the language chosen by the user into the model. So I guess this middleware doesn't work. or it doesn't do the job I want.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the language preference to the database is an overhead that you can avoid using the tools that Django offers.

[`django.utils.translation.get_language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language), returns the language used in the current thread.

As documented [in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates), this is an example:

```
from django.utils import translation

def welcome_translated(language):
    cur_language = translation.get_language()
    try:
        translation.activate(language)
        text = translation.gettext('welcome')
    finally:
        translation.activate(cur_language)
    return text
```

You can also use [`django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language_from_request) to analyze the request to find what language the user wants the system to show, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649210/2996101).

Be sure, however, that you have correctly [setup Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/).

Marina Mele has written [a tutorial](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones#inter-settings) you can check out for a second point of view.

Comment: useful answer. but some here are more explanations about what I meant: `for user in all_users: send_email_to_user(user,his_language_preference)`.... do you understand? language will render the template in his language

Comment: @EuChi OK, I see, you need to send an email after the session is concluded. I think it is better to ask the user in a registration form, what is his preferred language of communication.

Comment: I did, there is a select dropdown where the user can choose his language, made with the built-in django function. so I want to be able to know within the loop when sending email, how to render the templates in the chosen language of a specific user.

Comment: @EuChi Can you update the question with the code used to collect the information from the user and save it to the database?

Comment: No I can't this is what I can't do. I want to knwo how to do it, how to get it when the changes his language. I thought Django had a signal for that