# How to show Language code in field label in Django translated fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-translated-fields

i used django translated fields to create some monolingual fields in my models.
It works good, but in admin page, in add page, there is two same fields for every translated fields i created.
How can i show language code for each field?

[What it is showing now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YS1I.png)

[What i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPCJB.png)

*Update:
I added this code in my translated field and now it shows what i want. But I'm looking for an automatic way to do it.

```
{
    "en": {"verbose_name": _('File Title')+' (en)'},
    "de": {"verbose_name": _('File Title')+' (de)'}
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356964/how-can-i-get-the-current-language-in-django) might help

Comment: @BrianD Thanks, but it just returns language code. I want the language code to be written in field labels automatically.