# Logging incorrect translations in Django

Tags: python, django, localization

I often run into the mistake of using `gettext` in a context where the actual language is not set yet - instead of using the appropriate `gettext_lazy`.

Those errors can be difficult to catch - I would like to make them more visible appropriate logging, or possibly even throwing exceptions.

- Would it be correct, to write a wrapper function that logs an error in the case of `get_language() is None`?
- Then of course, one would need to enforce that this wrapper is always used - introducing another subtle easy to make mistake. In general, I suppose monkey-patching could be used, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. The whole dispatch behind `django.util.translation` seems already relatively complex. Is there a clean way too hook this functionality in there?

Comment: Here is the link to get the idea
[Get the current language in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356964/how-can-i-get-the-current-language-in-django)

Comment: if you're willing to wrap and enforce each occurrence of `gettext` why not script a refactoring of `gettext` to `gettext_lazy`?

Comment: @gregory's suggestion is a good one:

`django.utils.translation.gettext = django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy`

Comment: @gregory a full discussion on always using `gettext_lazy` over `gettext` would be interesting, but doesn't fit in a comment. And it's not exactly the point of this question - even in that case, I am still reluctant to blindly use monkey-patching. And I even with a refactoring. I still have no means to enforce not using a standard Django function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Django's built-in checks for this. Django provides a check_for_language function that raises a LanguageStoreNotAvailable exception if the language is not set. You can use this function in your code to check for the availability of the language before calling gettext or gettext_lazy.

```
from django.utils.translation import check_for_language, gettext

def my_function():
    check_for_language()
    return gettext('Hello, world!')
```

If the language is not set, this will raise a LanguageStoreNotAvailable exception.

Alternatively, you can use Django's gettext_lazy function, which returns a TranslatableString object that will be translated when it is rendered in a template or when force_text is called on it. This avoids the need to call gettext at all and ensures that the translation is not performed until the language is set.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy

def my_function():
    return gettext_lazy('Hello, world!')
```

This will return a TranslatableString object that can be used in your code or templates, and the translation will be performed when it is rendered.

Overall, it's generally best to use gettext_lazy whenever possible to avoid the need to explicitly check for the availability of the language. This helps to avoid subtle errors and makes your code more robust.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses my two specific questions.

Comment: @Zulan, maybe this answer is created using ChatGPT? There are some suspicious similarities between this answer and the other (that just got deleted because of it).